# Get categories per store using SOAP in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v1

In Magento 1 need to make a SOAP call for a certain category in order to extract information.

For that I use below request:

```
$result_ = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.info', 90);
```

However, since the store is in multiple languages I need to send along a store_id to be able to collect the information per store.

I have tried below with no success:

```
$result_ = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.info', array(array('category_id'=>array('eq'=>'90')),array('store'=>array('eq'=>'4'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to sort it. Solution below:

```
$result_ = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.info', array('category_id' => '90', 'store' => '4'));
```